# Arrow functions best practice?

Tags: javascript

Is it best practice to use arrow functions, when the function takes one parameter?

I was told to use something like this

```
const volumeOfSphere =  diameter =>
   (1/6) * Math.PI * diameter * diameter * diameter;
```

Rather than this

```
const volumeOfSphere = (diameter) => {
    return (1/6) * Math.PI * diameter * diameter * diameter;
};
```

I know with time the first example will pop out to me as a function when skimming  code, but the second example is more easily identifiable as a function to me.

Comment: They are the same.  You don't need parens around a single param.

Comment: Note that both your examples are "arrow functions."  The former is generally preferable for simple calculations.

Comment: Either  one is good. all depends of the linter rules you are using

Comment: Does your team use a linter or coding guide that requires this style?

Comment: While they would be the same... I'd strongly prefer the second option. Note that [**ESLint prefers the latter**](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-confusing-arrow). I guess this would come down to personal opinion, which is considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow.

Comment: `const volumeOfSphere =  diameter =>  1/6 * Math.PI * diameter**3`

Comment: I will add that "They are the same" is not an opinion.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to use it as a function, the second one is ok, if it helps you identify it is a function. Although if using the arrow function inline(for example passing it to `map` or `filter`) it is more readable using the first one. The most important thing is to be consistent across your codebase and follow company or team rules and style if you work in one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Airbnb Javascript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#arrows--one-arg-parens), you should omit the parens when there's only 1 parameter.